# How to retrieve Display attribute in the Html Helper (GroupName)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

In the HtmlHelper I'm trying to retrieve DisplayAttribute.GroupName of a property, by using

```
 ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData)
```

However, property "GroupName" is missing in the ModelMetadata.

I googled for solutions and all I saw were quite complex manipulations, while I hope that this can be solved easier.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an example that may work. I use this to create a custom helper. Hope this works for you:

```
 public static MvcHtmlString DatePickerFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string className)
 {
     if (expression == null)
     {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");
     }
     var expressionText = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
     var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
     var me = (expression.Body as MemberExpression);
     var display = me
                .Member
                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false)
                .Cast<DisplayAttribute>()
                .FirstOrDefault();
     string paramDisplayName = display.Name; //this is what you need
     return  new MvcHtmlString(DatePicker(htmlHelper, expressionText, className, htmlHelper.ViewData.Eval(expressionText), validations));
}
```

And this is how I call this method:

```
@Html.DatePickerFor(model => model.SelectedMilestone.DeliveryDate, "core2-form-textbox-date")
```